# Best recovery for elementry os

Tags: elementary-project, backup

What is the best over-all recovery program/procedure
for elementary ?
(Is the a way to backup in a way that the instance (system + my files) is fully recovered ? from external disk)
Ilan

Answer (score 0):

I have had success using Timeshift for the elementary os system files and Back in Time for my personal files. I go over my reasoning and the procedure I use in [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbly4RS_EZc)